# GSAP Scroll based animation with React breaking

Tags: css, reactjs, gsap, scrolltrigger

I am using two different scroll based animation in two consecutive components which are working fine on their own i.e.. if i turn on either one of them they are working fine..
but it breaks when i turn both of them on it breaks.

the components I am taking about are pixelPerfectionist and Easter cube in App.js.

you can turn the use effect on and off in both these components to turn on/off the animation.

https://github.com/drifter089/another_one

next component jumps up after first animation.
so i treied to put blank section in middle of components.